# Check isvalid for jQuery validation server-side

Tags: asp.net, jquery-plugins

I'm migrating from ASP.net validation to the jQuery validation plugin to validate my pages. Is it possible to identify if the controls are valid server-side? ASP.net validation provides `page.IsValid`, I am looking for something similar?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Because javascript is not 100% full-proof (and I can't think of a good reason not to treat all users as malicious), it's **always** best practice to validate on server-side, even if there is validation on the client-side.

This isn't to say that there's not value in validating forms via javascript (or ajax) for a greater user experience, but these validations should *also* take place in an environment in which you control.

Answer (score 0):

You may place a flag on an **hidden input**, and read this value on post back, but this is too riscky, anyone can hack it - and also if some one disable the javascript, your validation is not going to work.

**Its better to make again validation on your values on post back** (at least this is what I do).